# Use plist/XML to download and cache detailed data?

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am an experienced C++/Java programmer but am new to iOS.

I am writing an iPhone application that allows the user to browse a very small amount of detailed hierarchical data, say, 10 books in a catalog. The app will have all the data on the phone. Initially, the app can be deployed to the app store without any data or a static set of data, but as the user uses the app over time, the app should download and cache new or modified content from my server. (E.g. If a book is deleted or is added to the catalog, it should be reflected in the user's phone.)

What is the best way of doing this? I know that I want to poll my server when my app starts to check for new updates (e.g. check a file on the server that holds the last update timestamp). Now, in what format should I download new data? How should I maintain this data? Should I just download plist/XML files and manage them on the iPhone, or should I do something more sophisticated with SQLLite?

Again, the amount of data is relatively small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would populate your initial data set with a pList shipped with the app (so you don't need to wait for the network response on startup). I would refresh the data with a request for JSON data from the server ([a good Objective-C JSON parser](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)).

Given your small data set, I wouldn't go to the extra effort of an SQLLite DB. You can just stick that data in memory and persist it in flat files.  Check out [NSData writeToFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I'm very familiar with XML but not JSON. Is it preferrable these days? Also, I don't know much about NSData; is it the same approach as maintaining a plist in memory and writing/reading it from file?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 NSData is just a wrapper for a buffer full of bytes. You can use it to store the string of JSON (or XML if you prefer) that you get back from the server.  I prefer JSON over XML, but there are decent XML parsers around as well, so either is fine.